# Nginx virtual host not goes into infint loading with docker compose

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I have configure nginx server block like below. when I try to access my domain "exampleweb.loc" it goes in infinit loading. but when I access it by localhost or its IP "10.1.0.100" it is working perfact.

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/localhost.decrypted.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    root /var/www/html/exampleweb.loc;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name exampleweb.loc;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass php82:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param origin_is $host;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```